# ajax load insert before element

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery, load

I want to have the jQuery AJAX load to insert before the navigation as-is instead of replacing the contents of an element.

I'm trying to accomplish this by loading it in a new div before the navigation, but I'm having trouble unwrapping it as `.unwrap()` unwraps the parent and not the current div. Trying to unwrap the divs `.children()` breaks my AJAX load.

```
navigation.before(
    $('<div />')
        .load(nextLink + ' .post', function() {
            pageNum++;
            nextLink = nextLink.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]?/, '/page/'+ pageNum);

            if(pageNum <= max) {
                navigation.children('a').text('Load More');
            }
            else {
                navigation.children('a').text('Nothing else to load.');
            }
        })
);
```

If you're wondering where this came from, it's a modified version of [Load Next WordPress Posts With AJAX](http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('<div />')
    .load(nextLink + ' .post', function() {
        pageNum++;
        nextLink = nextLink.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]?/, '/page/'+ pageNum);

        if(pageNum <= max) {
            navigation.children('a').text('Load More');
        }
        else {
            navigation.children('a').text('Nothing else to load.');
        }

        navigation.before($(this).html());
    });
```